# Soft Hypen in Unicode Not Rendering

Tags: html, css, web, unicode, html-entities

I have created a set of CSS utilities for rendering html entities as icons and most of them are rendering.

I'm having a problem with the soft hyphen utility.  It's not rendering at all.  This is the code (I'll put it next to the copyright sign which is rendering just for contrast):

```
    .u-icon-soft-hyphen::before {
        content: '\000AD' !important;
    }

    .u-icon-copyright-sign::before {
        content: '\000A9' !important;
    }
```

[This is the test](https://superflycss.github.io/utilities-icons/target/test/html/).  If you search for `u-icon-soft-hyphen` you will see that it is not rendering.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The soft hyphen is not supposed to display on-demand like that. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen):

> [The soft hyphen] serves as an invisible marker used to specify a place in text where a hyphenated break is allowed without forcing a line break in an inconvenient place if the text is re-flowed. It becomes visible only after word wrapping at the end of a line.

Comment: Aha!  Learned something new today.  That's pretty cool!  I'll have to repurpose the unit testing around that.

Comment: @Ole I also learned something new, so thanks for the interesting question.